# Как убрать лишние пробелы в выводе smarty

Tags: регулярные-выражения, yii2, smarty

Есть проблема с выводом заголовков из таблицы в шаблон yii2 с помощью smarty
заголовок выводится через эту команду:

```html
<strong>Объект «{$object->name|safe}»</strong>
```

а в коде получается что-то подобное:

```html
<strong>Объект «Заголовок                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                » </strong>
```

то есть после заголовка вставляется огромное количество пробелов, причем разное количество пробелов для любых заголовков, видимо это зависит от длины заголовка.
Поэтому нужно удалять пробелы если их больше двух подряд, а я умею только все сразу:

```html
Объект «{$object->name|safe|regex_replace:"/\s+/":""}»
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить все пробелы, если их больше двух. Буду благодарен если поможете регулярным выражением или подскажете от чего пробелы могут добавляться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по описанию `Smarty` можно воспользоваться модификатором `strip`, который заменит повторяющиеся пробелы на один пробел

```
<strong>Объект «{$object->name|safe|strip}»</strong>
```

или модификатором `regex_replace` с регуляркой `/\s+$/` (она захватит только пробелы в конце строки)

```
<strong>Объект «{$object->name|safe|regex_replace:"/\s+$/":""}»</strong>
```

Comment: еще удобно срабатывает |trim

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = a.replace(/\s\s+/g , ' ');
```

Comment: Я smarty не знаю, но это точно будет работать в smarty? А то выглядит как javascript.